# I can't stop a grails application (3.2.8)

Tags: grails, grails3

I start a grails application (3.2.8) with "grails run-app". It takes the defaults and start at "http://localhost:8080".
From IntelliJ, or even from the windows terminal I invoke "grails stop-app" and I get the following message:
| Application not found via JMX, attempting remote shutdown.
| Shutting down application...
| Error Application not running.

In application.groovy I added:
grails.project.fork.run = true

with no effect.
What is the right way to stop the server? I particularly need it when I set dbCreate = 'create-drop' to clean the database.

Comment: Starting and stopping from IntelliJ works well on Windows 7 for me.  Can you try starting using IntelliJ?  What OS are you using?

Comment: I see you commented here, but this appears to be a grails bug and there is no right way at the moment.  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10724

Comment: I'm working on Windows 7 and using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.5
Yes, I believe it is a grails bug, but it was closed for 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your build.gradle?

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}
```

Otherwise do you have a g:include?  Could be this issue:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10411

Comment: Yes, I have those lines. No, I don't have a g:include, I don't have GSPs, we will use json views.

Answer (score 0):

I see this with the simplest of apps in 3.3.3. I tracked it down to permissions on the Spring Boot "shutdown" endpoint. I fixed it by adding the following to *grails-app/conf/application.yml*:

```
management:
    security:
        enabled: false
```

Since this works, I assume "grails stop-app" is essentially doing this:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/shutdown
```

I'm new to Grails, so there may be a better solution that doesn't require dropping down to the Spring Boot level.

Comment: Your suggestion is quite interesting, but I tried in grails4 and is not working. I don't know if grails4 is so new that it has issue on stop-app indipendently